# Confused about logistic regression equality

Tags: regression, machine-learning, self-study, maximum-likelihood

**Problem: Prove that:**
\begin{align}
\Delta E(in) &= -\frac{1}{N}  \sum_{n=1}^N  \frac{y_n  x_n}{1 + e^{(y_n w^t  x_n)}}  \\[10pt]
&=\frac{1}{N} * \sum_{n=1}^N - y_n  x_n  \theta  (-y_n  w^T  x_n)
\end{align}

Problem Description: I'm trying to prove this equality but I'm finding that my answer is not making any sense to me. Does anyone have a clue about this equality?

My doubt is about $\theta$, if theta is the log regression, then how the 
$...+e^{-...}$ is supposed to become positive? $...+e^{+...}$

Also, $e$ from the logistic regression, has only -x, and in the formula there are a lot of variables!

**On The Equality**

The denominator is being 'powered' by $y_n w^T x_n$. However, on the logistic regression, $e ^{-x}$. So how is logistic regression supposed to have more variables than X? Unless I consider that X can be anything. Which is obvious to me, but I'm not sure. And about the **sign** "-/+"

---

**Edit:**
The questions goes further, inferring that this equality would make "misclassified" examples contribute more to the gradient. However, logistic regression just calculates p(x|y), so how is that supposed to change anything? Also the range is just from $0\to 1$, so negative values wouldn't change either, since they aren't supposed to be inserted anyway.

So what about that? Unless I could add a variable to penalize misclassified values, I fail to see how that equality changes anything.

**Conclusion**
*This was my first question here, and I  did the tour and learning the rules and applying them! Sorry for anything!*

*References*

[Wikipedia - Logistic Regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression)

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you is grounds for closing.

Comment: It would also help to include a little more of the context for this question - particularly to define your variables.

Comment: Will do @Silverfish ! I just need a bit more time!

Comment: How can i approve the edits? Do i need to aprove anything? Thanks for editing! I really appreciate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose $θ$ is the logistic function $θ(x) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$.
Now, let's rewrite your initial formula like this (notice I also moved the minus into the summation):
$$
ΔE(in) = \frac{1}{N}*\sum\limits_{i=1}^N(-y_nx_n * \frac{1}{1+e^{-(-y_nw^Tx_n)}})
$$
It is clear that $\frac{1}{1+e^{-(-y_nw^Tx_n)}} = θ(-y_nw^Tx_n)$. Substituting this into the first equation we get the needed equality:
$$
ΔE(in) = \frac{1}{N}*\sum\limits_{i=1}^N(-y_nx_n * θ(-y_nw^Tx_n))
$$
Please ask if you need further help.

Comment: I was stuck with the "-" sign ! , i was going through the wrong way! Now i see everything makes sense and its so simple! Thanks so much! Does this change changes how the gradient will be calculated?